# Android Call Recording

Tags: java, android, call, record

```
setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK);
setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_UPLINK);
```

I am new to android and i am trying to save/record call voice.Any one of the above not recording any kind of voice.i google it every where but no success.After searching i found that phone recording depends on the the android phone.Because the media server(Audio Flinger) provided with android os is not capable of doing so.

http://forum.dailymobile.net/index.php?topic=60929.0;wap2

https://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/source/08defa03546578b8c71a26668de8ff8feed727fd:libs/audioflinger/AudioFlinger.cpp

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatAndroid.asp

**Any one who know the solution please answer.**

Comment: This is *not supposed* to be achievable.  It's also been covered here many times before.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=926498

Answer (score 0):

The following is working for me:

```
m_mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
m_mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
m_mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
m_mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Comment: I already tried that as i mentioned above..but not working for me. i am debugging on Motorola razor.